# Cross Platform File Exists & Read In C++

Tags: c++, file

How can I write two simple cross platform (Linux, Windows) functions for reading text file, and determine if some file exists?

I don't want to use a big library like Boost.IO for that. It's a very small plugin for some software and I don't think it's neccsary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library should be sufficient. [`access`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) will tell you if a file exists, and (if it's there) you can read with a normal `std::ifstream`.

Comment: What is the full name and type of `access`? Is it a function or a class? It is difficult to search with this general word effectively on Google.

Comment: @Notinlist: I've added a link that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// portable way to get file size; returns -1 on failure; 
// if file size is huge, try system-dependent call instead
std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    in.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end)
    return in.tellg(); 
}
```